# How to be a group owner in WifiDirect in Android?

Tags: android

I have reference the `WifiDirectExample` at Android SDK.  It can scan and connected to other device by WiFi-Direct.

The scenario for me is two device call **Device-A** and **Device-B**. The **Device-A** always initiative invite and connect to the **Device-B**.

I want the **Device-A** always become **Group owner**. But sometimes the **Device-A** has not become a **Group owner**.

**Does someone can teach me how to be a group owner in WifiDirect in Android ?**

I have no idea...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Device-A create a group.

```
 wifiP2pManager.createGroup(wifiP2pChannel, null);
```

Other devices connect to this group. The hostAddress in your case is Device-A address (WifiP2pDevice.deviceAddress).

```
private void connect(WifiP2pDevice host){

    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = host.hostAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;

    wifiP2pManager.connect(wifiP2pChannel, config, null);
}
```

config.groupOwnerIntent is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll use

`wifiP2pManager.createGroup(Channel c, ActionListener listener)`

you'll get an Autonomous Group Owner and other devices can join it.

But, if you want to create a group (sometimes called standard) you can use:

`config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;`

to force a device to connect as a Group Owner and

`config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;`

to force a device to connect as a Client.

Attention, "config.groupOwnerIntent" doesn't ensure the a device will be a Group Owner or a Client, but based on my experience, the probability is high.

Depends on the desired group type.